# sql запрос с выборкой по букве

Tags: sql

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как сформировать sql запрос:
Выбрать * В таблице ГДЕ первая буква А.
Пытался вот так, ничего не вышло:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='А%'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE 'А%'
```

Comment: Выводит ошибку: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '='�%' at line 1

Comment: Сам запрос выглядит вот так "SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE='А%"

Comment: Знак = после LIKE не нужен

Comment: @Димон в моем запросе не было знака равно

Answer (score 4):

Для таких целей в SQL есть специальный оператор `LIKE`. Ваш запрос должен принять вид

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE name LIKE 'A%'
```

Comment: Фильтр заработал, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать запрос посредством $_GET. К примеру в url имеется ссылка вида site.ru/?word=a и как сделать что бы значение 'a' уходило в переменную $test и запрос уже формировался так SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE name LIKE '$test%'

Comment: @Димон самый примитивный и весьма уязвий способ `GET` методом: `mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '$test%'");`. Однако вам следует сначала проверять значение в `GET`

Comment: SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE name LIKE 'A%' Это всё круто, но что делать если у меня переменная, а не готовая буква?
Если это я вызываю например `call primer ('а');`

Comment: _"но что делать если у меня переменная, а не готовая буква?"_ - задать новый вопрос. Вы дали "ответ" и здесь вам никто не ответит.